# Jenkins Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have the following problem, when executing Jenkins Job, I get the following error:

[error_sq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFV3j.png)

INFO:
Java Version: 7
SonnarQube : 6.7.3-alpine
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.3.0.1333
Jenkins Version: 2.107.3

Help me pls...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run an application with a JVM with a lower version number than the class was compiled with. Class version 52.0 equates to Java 1.8, and you are probably using 1.7, 1.6 or even lower. There will be no problem running it with a 1.8 or higher VM.

You can check your VM version by executing `java -version`.